# Add HTML to an image and download using php

Tags: php

I am trying to add following HTML table to an image and then download it as an .jpg file but instead it giving me white image which is given in `$dir`. Please have a look and guide what i am missing or what is wrong with this code

```
$dir = "../images/white.jpg";

$text = "tableHTML";
imagettftext($dir, 20, 0, 10, 20, $text);

imagepng($dir);
//$name = './img/ok.png';
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: public, no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($dir) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

readfile($dir);
```

the output image.jpg would be like this

```
Sr # | ID    | Bar Code  | Notes
1    | 1261  | ||||||||  | Test
2    | 6781  | ||||||||  | test 
3    | 8895  | ||||||||  | test 
4    | 5578  | ||||||||  | test 
5    | 1123  | ||||||||  | test
```

*test data

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one parameter.
Following the documentation -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )

you're using

imagettftext((image)$dir, (size)20, (angle)0, (x)10, (t)20, (color)$text);

maybe you're missing the color before the text ;)

Comment: i tried it but it download the image_download.php file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a jpg file and you are using `imagepng()` function.

Your code could have been like ---

```
$file = 'images/white.jpg';
$text = "tableHTML";
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$file = ImageCreateFromJPEG($file); 
$font = 'YOUR_FONT_FILE_PATH';
$black = ImageColorAllocate($file, 255, 255, 255);
Imagettftext($file, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, "text to write");
imagejpeg($file);
```

Comment: I have applied your code but it does not work it gives output like this

"����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� "

Comment: You have to define content type also. See I have modified the ans.

Comment: i have applied your modified code but it is just showing little image.. not any text or something inside the image

Comment: Check whether the font is working fine or not....also change the position of text. check documentation of Imagettftext() , you will understand.

Comment: $font = 'YOUR_FONT_FILE_PATH'; this line... give your font path and place exact font file (eg. Arial.ttf) there